# How to set localStorage item in webView before loading a URLRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have to access a web page that has token on its localStorage

```
let javascript = "localStorage.setItem('token', 'abc')"
let url = URL(string: "https://test.com/abc")
webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (_, err) in
        print(err?.localizedDescription)
        // This will return 'A JavaScript exception occurred'
    }
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.load(request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **i solve it but i think it's a bad practice and the right way was to be able to send token in request's header**

the main problem was that you can't run javascript script that add localStorage item before the web view load so i had to wait utile that page is loaded then then run javascript script that add needed token then reload that page Here is my code but again it's bad practice i think and i believe that front end team should allow me to end that token in request header
fist there was that method with reload the web view only one time

```
var loaded = false
func load() {
    if !loaded {
        webView.reload()
    }
    loaded = true
}
```

then i had to confirm to WKNavigationDelegate delegate to reload that page when it's loaded and here is my code

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (_, err) in
            self.load()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is possible. You get this error:

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 
"A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, 
WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SecurityError: The operation is 
insecure., WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, 
NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
```

And there nothing you can do about for the WKWebView.

Comment: I'm getting the same error now, but it seems it used to be possible judging from earlier posts I found on google. Any idea if Apple has changed their policy on this?